# How can I subtract two variables in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am getting error an error in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
value='55'
size=`df -kh | grep '/vol/cdr/MCA' | awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/%//g'`
if [ "$size" -gt "$value" ] ;
then
delete=[ "$size" - "$value" ]
echo $delete
fi
```

Output:

```
[root@rohit ~]# sh -x test.sh
+ value=55
++ df -kh
++ grep /vol/cdr/MCA
++ awk '{print $5}'
++ sed s/%//g
+ size=78
+ '[' 78 -gt 55 ']'
+ delete='['
+ 78 - 55 ']'
test.sh: line 6: 78: command not found
+ echo
```

Comment: If your problem was solved, please consider [accepting an answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Your shell arithmetic problem has been answered....but your extraction of the fliesystem's used-percentage is more complicated than it needs to be: with GNU `df`:   `size=$(df --output=pcent /vol/cdr/MCA | tail -n +2 | sed -e 's/ \|%//g')`.  BTW, if you're using `awk`, you don't need to use `grep`, e.g. `awk '/\/vol\/cdr\/MCA/ {print $5}'`

Answer (score 4):

The `[ ... ]` syntax is actually a *command*, not anything special to the shell at all.  It is another name for the `test` command—see `man test` or even just `man [`.

What you want is *arithmetic evaluation*:

```
delete="$((size-value))"
```

---

What is happening in your code is that since you didn't quote the value you are assigning to the variable, that whole line was split into words by the shell:

```
delete=[
"$size"
-
"$value"
]
```

The first of these is handled as a variable assignment, assigning the string `"["` to the variable `delete`; the rest of it is then considered as a command.

Since 78 (the expansion of `"$size"`) is not a valid command, the shell throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do math right? In that case, replace:

```
delete=[ "$size" - "$value" ]
```

with

```
delete=$(($size-$value))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value=55
size=42
declare -i result    # set integer attribute
result=$value-$size
echo $result
```

Output:

```
13
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern shell scripting the correct syntax for this is:

```
value=55
size=42
result=$(( value - size ))
```

Comment: This is basically the same as [DisplayName’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283295/80216#283297), but you have switched the order of the operands.

Answer (score 0):

### Diff Real Positive Numbers

```
diff_real () {
  echo "df=($1 - $2); if (df < 0) { df=df* -1}; print df" | bc -l;
}
```

### Usage

```
var_a=10
var_b=4

output=$(diff_real $var_a $var_b)
# 6

#########


var_a=4
var_b=10

output=$(diff_real $var_a $var_b)
# 6
```